# Nvidia NVS 4200M Problems on Lenovo T420S

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, video, intel

I have a problem in getting the NVIDIA card to load.  I get the classic "no screens" found.  I've even forced it to used "ConnectedMonitor" DFP-0 for my laptop screen.

I suspect that something is wrong with my settings that will recognize my flat panel.  My NVIDIA drivers do not see it and then Optimus kicks in the onboard intel video drivers and it loads up X that way.

I have tried all the different variations with no avail (Nouveau, bumblebee+nvidia_current, nvidia-current alone, and NVIDIA drivers from NVIDIA site).

Interestingly enough, if I attach a monitor via DVI connector through a docking station, NVIDIA drivers load up successfully and finds DFP-3.  The external monitor gets Unity loaded, but the laptop monitor goes blank.

HELP!

## Current xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Screen         "Screen0" Relative "Screen1" 0 0
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen         "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "SendCoreEvents" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "SendCoreEvents" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Samsung"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMS27A850"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 90.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVS 4200M"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVS 4200M"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "MetaModes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select, nvidia-auto-select"
    Option         "TwinView" "true"
    Option         "RandRRotation" "true"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1600x900" "1920x1080" "2560x1440"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "true"
    Option         "RandRRotation" "true"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1600x900" "1920x1080" "2560x1440"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

## LSPCI Results

lspci -nn | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:1056] (rev a1)

## My GPU INFO

### nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info

### if I *don't* have the external monitor connected and I query GPU info:

```
Number of GPUs: 1

GPU #0:
  Name      : NVS 4200M
  PCI BusID : PCI:1:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 0
```

if I *do* have it ... it shows me that I have one Display Device connected.

## My Xorg.0.log:

```
    [     7.228] 
X.Org X Server 1.10.1
Release Date: 2011-04-15
[     7.228] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     7.228] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Sep 30 20:39:30 2011
[     7.229] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     7.229] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     7.229] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     7.229] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     7.229] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     7.229] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     7.229] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     7.229] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     7.229] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     7.229]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.229] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.229]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.229] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.229]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.230] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     7.230]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.230] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     7.230]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.230] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[     7.230] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     7.230] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     7.230] (II) Loader magic: 0x7e17e0
[     7.230] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     7.230]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     7.230]    X.Org Video Driver: 10.0
[     7.230]    X.Org XInput driver : 12.3
[     7.231]    X.Org Server Extension : 5.0
[     7.231] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0126:17aa:21d3 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf1400000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64
[     7.231] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:1056:17aa:21d3 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf0000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     7.231] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[     7.231] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[     7.233] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[     7.233] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.233]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.233]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     7.233]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     7.233] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     7.233] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     7.233] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[     7.233] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[     7.233] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[     7.233] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     7.233] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[     7.233] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[     7.233] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[     7.233] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.233]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.233]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     7.233]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     7.233] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     7.233] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     7.233] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     7.312] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     7.313]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.313]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     7.313] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  280.13  Wed Jul 27 17:12:07 PDT 2011
[     7.313] (II) Loading extension GLX
[     7.313] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[     7.314] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[     7.314] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.314]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.13.0
[     7.314]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     7.314]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     7.314] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[     7.314] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[     7.314] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[     7.314] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.314]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.314]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     7.314] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[     7.314] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     7.315] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[     7.315] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.315]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.2.0
[     7.315]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     7.315] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[     7.315] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[     7.315] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[     7.315] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[     7.315] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     7.315] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     7.317] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     7.322] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.322]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 2.14.0
[     7.322]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.322]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[     7.322] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     7.323] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[     7.323] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     7.323] (II) Unloading vesa
[     7.323] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[     7.323] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     7.323] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     7.324] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.324]    compiled for 1.10.0, module version = 0.4.2
[     7.325]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[     7.325] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
    i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
    E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
    965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
    4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
    Sandybridge, Sandybridge, Sandybridge, Sandybridge, Sandybridge,
    Sandybridge, Sandybridge
[     7.325] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     7.325] (++) using VT number 7

[     7.327] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     7.327] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     7.327] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     7.327] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     7.327] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     7.327] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.327]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 0.0.2
[     7.327]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[     7.328] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     7.328] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     7.328] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:02.0
[     7.328] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     7.328] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     7.328] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[     7.328] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:02.0
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     7.328] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     7.328] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[     7.328] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) Sandybridge
[     7.328] (--) intel(0): Chipset: "Sandybridge"
[     7.328] (**) intel(0): Relaxed fencing enabled
[     7.328] (**) intel(0): Tiling enabled
[     7.328] (**) intel(0): SwapBuffers wait disabled
[     7.328] (==) intel(0): video overlay key set to 0x101fe
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 has no monitor section
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): found backlight control interface /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): EDID for output LVDS1
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer: SEC  Model: 324c  Serial#: 0
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Year: 2010  Week: 0
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Digital Display Input
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 31  vert.: 17
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Gamma: 2.20
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): redX: 0.566 redY: 0.337   greenX: 0.351 greenY: 0.560
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.094   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Supported detailed timing:
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): clock: 98.2 MHz   Image Size:  310 x 174 mm
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): h_active: 1600  h_sync: 1648  h_sync_end 1680 h_blank_end 1760 h_border: 0
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): v_active: 900  v_sync: 902  v_sync_end 907 v_blanking: 930 v_border: 0
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Unknown vendor-specific block f
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):  SAMSUNG
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):  LTN140KT03401
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): EDID (in hex):
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):     00ffffffffffff004ca34c3200000000
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):     00140103801f1178ea1d859156598f26
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):     18505400000001010101010101010101
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):     0101010101015d2640a060841e303020
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):     250036ae100000190000000f00000000
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):     000000000032c8043200000000fe0053
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):     414d53554e470a204ca34b54000000fe
[     7.328] (II) intel(0):     004c544e3134304b54303334303100ca
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     7.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "320x240" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "400x300" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "400x300" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "512x384" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "640x480" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "640x512" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "800x600" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "896x672" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "928x696" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "960x720" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "576x432" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "680x384" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "680x384" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "700x525" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "720x450" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "800x512" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "840x525" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "840x525" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "960x540" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "960x600" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "1024x768" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS1
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1360x768"x59.8   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   72.00  1360 1408 1440 1520  768 771 781 790 +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x60.0   81.62  1152 1216 1336 1520  864 865 868 895 -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz)
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): EDID for output VGA1
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 connected
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 disconnected
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 using initial mode 1600x900
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[     7.329] (II) intel(0): Kernel page flipping support detected, enabling
[     7.329] (**) intel(0): Display dimensions: (310, 170) mm
[     7.329] (**) intel(0): DPI set to (131, 134)
[     7.329] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     7.329] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     7.329] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     7.331] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.331]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.331]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     7.331] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     7.331] (II) Unloading fbdev
[     7.331] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     7.331] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[     7.331] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     7.331] (==) intel(0): VideoRam: 262144 KB
[     7.331] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     7.331] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[     7.331] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 1600x900 stride 6656, tiled
[     7.334] (II) UXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[     7.335] (II)         solid
[     7.335] (II)         copy
[     7.335] (II)         composite (RENDER acceleration)
[     7.335] (II)         put_image
[     7.335] (II)         get_image
[     7.335] (==) intel(0): Backing store disabled
[     7.335] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     7.335] (II) intel(0): Initializing HW Cursor
[     7.400] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[     7.401] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[     7.401] (==) intel(0): Intel XvMC decoder enabled
[     7.401] (II) intel(0): Set up textured video
[     7.401] (II) intel(0): [XvMC] xvmc_vld driver initialized.
[     7.401] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 Enabled
[     7.401] (==) intel(0): hotplug detection: "enabled"
[     7.401] (--) RandR disabled
[     7.401] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[     7.401] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[     7.401] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[     7.401] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[     7.401] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[     7.401] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[         7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[     7.402] (II) Initializing built-in extension GESTURE
[     7.404] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[     7.407] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 423 x 238
[     7.422] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[     7.431] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[     7.431] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     7.431] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[     7.431] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[     7.433] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.433]    compiled for 1.10.0.902, module version = 2.6.0
[     7.433]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     7.433]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 12.3
[     7.433] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     7.433] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[     7.433] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     7.433] (**) Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[     7.480] (--) Power Button: Found keys
[     7.480] (II) Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     7.926] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[     7.926] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     7.926] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[     7.926] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[     7.927] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     7.927] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[     7.927] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[     7.927] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     7.927] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[     7.928] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[     7.928] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     7.928] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[    14.024] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    14.024] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
[    14.028] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint (/dev/input/event9)
[   202.481] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[   202.482] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   202.482] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[   207.664] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[   207.665] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   207.665] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[   210.236] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[   210.236] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   210.236] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[   210.251] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[   210.251] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   210.251] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[  1456.762] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[  1456.762] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  1456.762] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[  3523.786] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[  3523.786] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  3523.786] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[  3832.025] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[  3832.025] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  3832.025] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[  4206.129] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[  4206.129] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  4206.129] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
[  4928.781] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12876
[  4928.781] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  4928.781] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   98.21  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 902 907 930 -hsync -vsync (55.8 kHz)
```

> enter code here

---

HELP!!!!

Comment: Why do you specify the bus id of the intel card for Device1? I've just got my nvidia card to work on a dell latitude e6520 with an external monitor; the nvidia settings manager specified the nvidia bus id for Device0 and Device1.

Comment: I have the same video card on my T520 and it works fine. I had to remove nouveau completely rebuild the ramfs and then installed drivers downloaded from nvidia which creates an xorg for you. One thing with Lenovos is you must change display settings in the Bios, they come precinfigured to be optimal for Windows 7, needs to be changed to discrete if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your hardware , but i get the same issues on my laptop with two graphic cards.

In my case its was caused by the fact that the other card is not connected to my internal laptop monitor( it can only be connected to one graphic card at a time. If you're unable to successfully switch on / off / the proper card and switch in on to the monitor. This is what you get.

I got it working by poking some memory addresses manually in grub. In your case you probably need to do something specific for your hardware. Have you triedd using switcheroo?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics